# How to edit css through scss files

Tags: css, scss-lint

Actually for a recent project i downloaded a theme (Admin Panel). It mostly contains **css** in parts in the form of **.scss** files . I tried  editing files directly from **style.css**  but nothing seems to change . so i did little bit of research and found that scss files need to compiled again . I don't know how to compile **.scss** files. On their github page i found that it can be changed with the help of following commands

```
gulp serve
```

I don't know the above command was to compile again scss into css but it didn't work 
So ,kindly help with this or just a provide a link to the tutorial from where i could learn this

Here's the link for the project that i have just downloaded
https://github.com/BootstrapDash/PurpleAdmin-Free-Admin-Template

Thanks in Advance

Comment: as much as I understand `gulp serve` should do a some things, among them, start a local server on port 3000 and also should compile the scss files. You can see the gulp command [here](https://github.com/BootstrapDash/PurpleAdmin-Free-Admin-Template/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L25). What exactly not working for you. Have you run `npm install` before?

Comment: Here's a link to the gulp documentation: https://gulpjs.org/getting-started

Comment: yes i did run npm install first

Comment: @MoshFeu can you take a look at directory structure of the project .Is it possible to re compile scss to modify css files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up a SCSS compiler for a project where you don't use SCSS yourself is tedious. Instead, try compiling it quickly and edit the CSS files after you compiled it.

You can use free compilers online, for example https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/.

If you would like to start a project with SCSS where you compile it, you can indeed use the GULP setup provided by Bootstrap.

https://mdbootstrap.com/bootstrap-gulp-tutorial/

You can also easily setup Gulp yourself:

https://codehangar.io/gulp-sass/

The above URL explains the following a little more extensive:

> npm install gulp-sass --save-dev

**Structure**:

```
-index.html
--assets
---styles
----sass
-----index.scss
----css
```

**The 'styles' Task**

```
//gulpfile.js

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

//style paths
var sassFiles = 'assets/styles/sass/**/*.scss',
    cssDest = 'assets/styles/css/';

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    gulp.src(sassFiles)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
});
```

**Watcher**

```
gulp.task('watch',function() {
    gulp.watch(sassFiles,['styles']);
});
```

> gulp watch